# Drupal 7 hook_schema not installing database table

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-hooks, drupal-schema

Any help would be brilliant.

```
function request_gold_pack_schema() {
    $schema['request_gold_pack_customer_details'] = array(
        'description' => 'Table to store all customer details.',
        'fields' => array(     
            'rid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',  
                'not null' => TRUE, 
                'default' => 0,
                'auto increment' => TRUE
            ),
            'title' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar', 
                'length' => 10,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => ''
            ),
            'first_name' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 50, 
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => ''
            ),
            'last_name' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 50,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => ''
            ),
            'house_name_no' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar', 
                'length' => 50,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => ''
            ),
            'street' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 160,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => ''
            ),
            'town' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 50,
                'not null' => TRUE, 
                'default' => ''
            ),
            'county' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar', 
                'length' => 50,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => ''
            ),
            'telephone' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'length' => 12,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => ''
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar', 
                'length' => 255,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => ''
            ),
            'date_registered' => array(
                'mysql_type' => 'DATETIME',
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
            'primary' => array(
                'rid'
            )
        )
    );

    return $schema;
}
```

which gives me the following errors

> Notice: Undefined index: type in DatabaseSchema_mysql->processField() (line 205 of /Users/richardskinner/Sites/www.goldrushmoney.com-local/httpdocs/includes/database/mysql/schema.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: :normal in DatabaseSchema_mysql->processField() (line 205 of /Users/richardskinner/Sites/www.goldrushmoney.com-local/httpdocs/includes/database/mysql/schema.inc).
>   PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'Table to stor' at line 13: CREATE TABLE {request_gold_pack_customer_details} ( `rid` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `title` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `last_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `house_name_no` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `street` VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `town` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `county` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `telephone` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `date_registered` DATETIME NOT NULL, `primary` DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'Table to store all customer details.'; Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2688 of /Users/richardskinner/Sites/www.goldrushmoney.com-local/httpdocs/includes/database/database.inc).

Been trying to find a solution for hours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an issue with your primary key. You hve it listed in the fields array (it should not be) and it should be referenced as 'primary key' and not 'primary', like so:

```
function request_gold_pack_schema(){
    $schema['request_gold_pack_customer_details'] = array(
        'description' => 'Table to store all customer details.',
        'fields' => array(     
              // Your field definitions
         ),
         'primary key' => array(
             'rid'
         )
    );
    return $schema;
}
```

Check out the [schema api documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7) on drupal.org.

I would also recommend setting the `rid` field to type `serial` and leaving off the auto increment parameter (Drupal will handle that).  So the 'rid' field definitions would be as such:

```
'rid' => array(
    'type' => 'serial',  
    'unsigned' => TRUE, 
    'not null' => TRUE, 
)
```

Comment: Actually, in the {node} example in the link you've given, the primary key is the first one listed under 'fields'. It's the same in the entity_example from the examples module that I'm working through at the moment. Perhaps it was just the primary/primary key issue? I might be wrong - I'm yet to get mine working.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the size in drupal 7 for type 'int'...i.e

```
'rid' => array(
'type' => 'int',  
'not null' => TRUE, 
'size' => 'normal',
'auto increment' => TRUE,
),
```

the size can be normal,tiny,big
check drupal 7 datatypes.